# iOS 11. Uitableview swipe action does not recognize the selected row after delete a cell

Tags: ios, ios11, swipe-gesture

I used the new API for iOS 11 to configure the swipe action of UITableView as below.

```
- (UISwipeActionsConfiguration *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  API_AVAILABLE(ios(11.0)){
if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {

    UIContextualAction *deleteAction = [UIContextualAction contextualActionWithStyle:UIContextualActionStyleDestructive
                                                                               title:@"Delete"
                                                                             handler:^(UIContextualAction * _Nonnull action, __kindof UIView * _Nonnull sourceView, void (^ _Nonnull completionHandler)(BOOL)) {

    [tableView.models removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone]; 
    [tableView reloadData];

    [tableView setEditing:NO animated:YES];

    completionHandler(YES);
}];

    UISwipeActionsConfiguration *config = [UISwipeActionsConfiguration configurationWithActions:@[deleteAction]];
    config.performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe = NO;
    return config;
} else {
    return nil;
}
}
```

At first, the swipe button shows correctly and deleted the selected row normally.

Then I try to continue swipe to finish delete action.

Then behaviour behaviour happened.

The row I just swiped acts as it can't be selected.

Eg, after deleted the second row. I tried to swipe the 4th cell, but the third cell get to be selected and ready to be swiped. The row that has weid behaviour are all belowed the row I just deleted.

Beside, the delete button's height is twice the height of the row.
As showed below is the screenshot of delete button.
[the delete button is abnormal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDSKt.jpg)

All bugs are met on iOS 11. As actions are normal on iOS 10.
Is this a bug of iOS 11? How to fix it? Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You're calling `reloadData` right after `deleteRows`. This is unnecessary and may introduce bugs as the one you have encountered. `deleteRows` along WILL update the tableView and should be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks at first.  It's right to not calling reloadData after deleteRows. But calling reloadData or deleteRows only, the row I just swiped can't be selected in iOS 11 sometimes. It acts as normal on other iOS system whose version is under 11.

Comment: If the only action is to delete, maybe ditch trailingSwipeActions altogether. Use only `tableView:canEditRowAt:`(which you return true for the rows you want to edit) `tableView:editingStyleForRowAt:`(which you return .delete for all rows), and `tableVIew:commitEditingForRowAt:editingStyle:`(which you handle the deletion and call tableView.deleteRows). The method signatures are probably not correct, as I'm writing this off my head. Google these signatures and you should see the true methods that you need to implement. They're a part of `UITableViewDelegate`

Comment: @Edward Jul  I use the old api:"commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath" as you answered. And the abnormal action still exist. I think it's a system bug of iOS 11 because these deviant  phenomenon only appears on iOS 11.* system.  Thanks anyway.